# Solving Leetcode SQL Question in R using plyr, dplyr and lubridate

Tags: r, date, time, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to solve the following Leetcode SQL database question in R.

Question: Write an R query that reports for every date within at most 90 days from today, the number of users that logged in for the first time on that date. Assume today is 2019-06-30.

Link to Leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/new-users-daily-count/

Here's what the data looks like:

```
Traffic <- cbind.data.frame(user_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                            activity = c("login","homepage","logout","login","logout","login","jobs",
                                         "logout","login","groups","logout","login","logout","login",
                                         "logout"),
                            activity_date = c("2019-05-01","2019-05-01","2019-05-01","2019-06-21",
                                              "2019-06-21","2019-01-01","2019-01-01","2019-01-01",
                                              "2019-06-21","2019-06-21","2019-06-21","2019-03-01",
                                              "2019-03-01","2019-06-21","2019-06-21"))
```

I tried 2 approaches in R using `lubridate()` and `dplyr()`

Approach 1: using the `interval()` and `as.period()` functions.

```
library("lubridate")
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

Today = lubridate::ymd("2019-06-30")

Traffic %>% dplyr::filter(activity == "login") %>% dplyr::filter(lubridate::day(lubridate::as.period(lubridate::interval(Today, lubridate::ymd(activity_date)), unit = "days")) <= 90) %>%
  plyr::ddply(.(user_id), transform, rank = rank(activity_date, ties.method = "min")) %>%
                dplyr::filter(rank == 1) %>% dplyr::group_by(activity_date) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(user_count = n())
```

This approach gives me the wrong answer below.
[image]

Approach 2:

```
Traffic %>% dplyr::filter(activity == "login") %>% dplyr::filter(abs(lubridate::day(Today) - lubridate::day(lubridate::ymd(activity_date))) <= 90 &
                                                                   abs(lubridate::month(Today) - lubridate::month(lubridate::ymd(activity_date))) < 3) %>%
  plyr::ddply(.(user_id), transform, rank = rank(activity_date, ties.method = "min")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(rank == 1) %>% dplyr::group_by(activity_date) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(user_count = n())
```

This gives me a better answer below but also with a wrong count for one of the result rows.
[image]

Here's the correct answer:
[image]

I want to find the reason why Approach 1 doesn't work and why Approach 2 gives me a wrong count for the second row.

Comment: You should avoid using `plyr`.

Comment: Hi, sure! how would you solve the ranking part of the question using dplyr's window functions?

Comment: Hi Martin, could you please be more specific as to why to avoid plyr? I find it quite useful for ranking within sub groups. Is it slower than dplyr and less efficient?

Comment: Your first solution does not work because the date interval yields negative numbers (they are in the past). Setting the comparison to `>= -90` should work.

Comment: I think most functions of `plyr` do have a similar implementation in `dplyr` minus the fact that they mask some functions from each other. I for one never missed `plyr`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `dplyr` and `lubridate` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Today <- ymd("2019-06-30")

Traffic %>% 
  filter(activity == "login") %>% 
  mutate(diff = ymd(activity_date) - Today) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  filter(all(abs(diff) <= 90)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  count(activity_date)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  activity_date     n
  <chr>         <int>
1 2019-05-01        1
2 2019-06-21        2
```

To answer your questions: you need to filter out all `user_id`'s whose earliest login date is more than 90 days away from 2019-06-30. So `user_id` needs to be filtered out. I don't think ranking is the right approach here, so basically that's my answer to your both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Martin. When I try to implement your approach in R, I get the below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vool8.png)

I changed the code a bit and it works now:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Today <- ymd("2019-06-30")

Traffic %>% 
  filter(activity == "login") %>% 
  mutate(diff = ymd(activity_date) - Today) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% 
  filter(all(abs(diff) <= 90)) %>% 
  group_by(activity_date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(user_count = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(login_date = activity_date) %>% dplyr::select(login_date, user_count)
```

To give the correct answer below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJw8j.png)

Comment: You could simplify your code by replacing your second `group_by` by `group_by(login_date = activity_date)` and removing the last line of your code. Furthermore your shouldn't need to use `dplyr::` in front of `summarize`. Is `plyr` still loaded? Perhaps this causes the error shown.